# When does meta become site policy?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, meta

I have asked a few times where the Arqade site policy states different things.  Many of these times, the response is a link to a Meta discussion.  I realize that the Meta is the place where the site's policy gets made and is intended to exists so we can smooth out the rules of the site as well as create new ones (among other reasons).

However, if we continually are pointing to Meta for our site policy, then when does a Meta become official policy?  Is any Meta with a positive score supposed to be taken as official or does it need to be above a certain number?  What if 2 answers have the same score and yet contradict?  What happens when mods disagree on policies derived from meta discussions?

On a side note, should there be a link to meta-decided policies in an easy-to-access area for new users? (If this should be a different meta it can be moved)

Comment: For the most part, if a single answer gets a rather distinct consensus (which varies on the question), it's accepted as the general rule.

Comment: And as a sidenote, you may want to read http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/am-i-allowed-to-stand-up-against-something-i-disagree-about

Comment: Honestly, that's a cop-out.  Dumping everything on our mods (based on a meta post at the beginning of the site) isn't really figuring out stuff ourselves.  And good luck applying that to half our policies.  [One of my very first meta answers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/4972/20456) is something we follow.

Comment: @fbueckert Who said anything about dumping everything on mods?  I also partially agree with you're linked answer.  However, we are also not in the business of assuming every new user will magically know what our rules are if they all exist in meta.  If you want to chastise those that do not read the FAQ then feel free.  If you want to chastise those that did not know a rule because it is not in the FAQ or the help or anywhere but a meta discussion, then that is just general douche-baggery.